# LAG and VLAN Problems

Tags: vlan

I have an extended star network between two buildings. In each building I have a "Main" switch. The two Dell N1524 switches are connected via 4 fibre optic links over SFP+.

Now the 4 links are aggregated via LAG (using LACP) and the LAG is set to Trunk in order to act as a tunnel for 5 VLANs.

When set up properly the network works just fine, but I have been experiencing an issue where seemingly at random, the LAG switches on one end from Trunk to DVLAN Tunnel. After which the entire LAG goes down.

Any ideas why such settings would change on their own accord? I am certain that no one is changing them.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on the physical links (both sides)?

Comment: Not that I can see.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dell but DVLAN seems to be QinQ double tagging. Is it possible that a double-tagged frame arrives at the switch somehow, causing it to switch to QinQ? Or possibly the EtherType used for DVLAN?

Comment: Please add the relevant configuration parts to your question. Much depends on how exactly you set up the trunk.

Comment: @Zac67 Yes DVLAN is qinq in Dell. I will check re double tagged frames and I will request a full config dump from my client.